# Fisher Paykel Washing Machine Model

Tags: washing-machine

Anyone knows what model is this washing machine?

I'm trying to look for the part but can't find its model number.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model gw712; see the back of the top panel next to the serial number.  Go on their web page, put in the serial number and get the parts list for that machine.